# Miinikube. Secrets not included in (only) one pod

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am testing a deployment on minikube.
It requires two pods, one is a webapp deloyment and one a chronjob

***For ChronJob:***

I start minikube and use

```
minikube addons configure registry-creds
minikube addons enable registry-creds
```

I use helm to deploy the the chronjob, the image pulls, the pod starts and I see the `awssecr-cred` in the pod

Everything works!

***For the web app:***

Rinse and repeat. Both are in default namespace, both deployed by helm to the same minikube deployment.

*However*, all secrets are missing from the webapp pod and, not surprisingly, cannot pull the image.

Can someone give me a pointer as to why the secrets are missing from this pod?

Comment: Can you share your helm chart chart here?

Comment: I think the reason was that it was under a different serviceAccountName